# Best way to parse pdf and word doc

Tags: parsing

I want to build an application that gets info out of a pdf or word doc and populate this into my database.

How do I go about this in the best way? Bare in mind that only certain information needs to be extracted from the pdf or word docu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse PDF, I know 2 choices :

### pdftotext

Check [pdf2text](https://github.com/robgraeber/pdf2text)

### OCR

try [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr)

Answer (score 0):

There are planty of free open source libs that will help you parsing the input file.

in the basic concepts- dont build the parser from scratch , 
use some open source lib to help you out.

if you will say in what lang you'r trying to write your code it may help:

---

for example for PDF your can find:

https://www.pdfparser.org/ (for php)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12445/Converting-PDF-to-Text-in-C (for C#)

and more.

for DOC\DOCX , pretty much the same.